# Postgresql insert table data into another table

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I've got a database with a table containing different calendars (`table events`). Now I created a new table (`events_backup`) and imported all entries from table events from an older backup.

Now I want to insert in the event table all entries for a specific calendar (`query calendar_id = 'foo'`) from `events_backup` but only if the don't exists.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into DESTINATION_TABLE 
select WANTED_COLUMNS 
where not exists 
     (select true 
          from SOURCE_TABLE 
          where query calendar_id = 'foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but is sounds as if you are just looking for:

```
insert into event (pk_column, e1.calendar_id, ...)
select e1.pk_column, e1.calendar_id, ...
from event e1
where e1.calendar_id = 'foo'
  and not exists (select 1 
                  from event e2 
                  where e2.pk_column = e1.pk_column);
```

The above assumes that there is a column named `pk_column` in the `event` table that is a primary or unique key.

Another alternative starting with Postgres 9.5 is to use the `on conflict` clause to ignore all inserts that would fail due to a unique constraint violation:

```
insert into event (pk_column, e1.calendar_id, ...)
select e1.pk_column, e1.calendar_id, ...
from event e1
on conflict do nothing;
```